# NoneType' object is not iterable ошибка нужна помощь

Tags: python

вот код ошибка падает начиная с not_city не понимаю как тогда верно написать

```
def check_address(text: str):
    nlu_address: Dict = nlu.extract_address(text)
    not_city = not all(nlu_address.get('city'))
    not_street = not all(nlu_address.get('street'))
    not_building = not all(nlu_address.get('building'))
    not_apartment = not all(nlu_address.get('apartment'))
    env_log(address=f'{not_city}, {not_building},{not_street},{not_apartment}')
```

Answer (score 0):

если адрес не найдет, то в `nlu_address` будет None

вы это не проверяете и пытаетесь получить `nlu_address.get('city')`

т.е. `None.get('city')` и соответственно получаете ошибку

Comment: а сделать нужно?

Comment: ну наверное, если адрес не существует, то выдать какое-нибудь сообщение, а не делать все эти лишние вычисления, делать или проверку или обернуть все вычисления в `try except`